# Evaluate $f(n)=\frac{(n-2)!!}{(n-3)!!}$, for $n \geq 3$ by Big O notation

Tags: functions, asymptotics

> Is there a better way than mine to evaluate this function
>
> $$f(n)=\frac{(n-2)!!}{(n-3)!!},\quad \text{for}\quad n \geq 3$$
>
> by Big O notation?

I got result below, but not so accurate. I know that:

$$n!!=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
       2^{k}k! &,n=2k\\
       \frac{(2k-1)!}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!} & , n=2k-1\\
       \end{array} \right.$$

So, I put this in $f(x)$ and got (for $x=\frac{n-2}{2}$, because for $n=2k$ function is always bigger in this case):

$$f(x)=\frac{2^{2x-1}x!(x-1)!}{(2x-1)!}$$

When I use asymptotic equation for $x$!:

$$x! = \sqrt{2\pi x}\bigg(\frac{x}{e}\bigg)^x\bigg(1+\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288n}+O(x^{-3})\bigg)$$

And notice that $e\gt2$ (I must somehow evalute $2^{2x-1}$ by Big O):

$$e^{2x-1} = 1 + 2x-1 + \frac{(2x-1)^2}{2!}+ O(x^{-3})$$

So now I connect everything, but for $n = 6$ i got error $0,3$ and it's too much
(because of my "fancy" evaluation $e\gt 2$). When I paste this into Wolfram it looks like a $O(\log)$ or $O(\sqrt{n})$ but I can't figure this out how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should analyze the even and odd cases separately since they have different asymptotics.

Also, there is no need to approximate $2^{2n}$ since it cancels out.

If $n = 2k$ we have

$$\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k-1)!!}=\frac{(2^k k!)^2}{(2k)!} = \frac{4^k\left(\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k\left(1+\frac{1}{12k}+\frac{1}{288k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi 2k}\left(\frac{2k}{e}\right)^{2k}\left(1+\frac{1}{12\cdot 2k}+\frac{1}{288\cdot 4k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)}=\sqrt{\pi k}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{12k}+\frac{1}{288k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)^2}{1+\frac{1}{12\cdot 2k}+\frac{1}{288\cdot 4k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)}=\sqrt{\pi k}\left(1+\frac{1}{8k}+\frac{1}{128k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)$$

A similar calculation can be done in the case of $n=2k+1$.

Comment: I was approximate $2^{2n}$ because i can't understand how to divide this Taylor series (to be more precise how you get your result when you are dividing your numerator by denominator, in last line, when they are different)

Comment: Could someone explain that? i don't get it

Comment: You can use long division, try it. If you still don't get it, ask for help again.

Comment: I returned to this example after a while and i can't still get it how to get yours result by long division.

Answer (score 3):

If we consider $$f(x)=\frac{2^{2x-1}\,x!\,(x-1)!}{(2x-1)!}$$ taking logarithms, using Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor expansions, we have
$$\log[f(x)]=\frac{1}{2} \log (\pi  x)+\frac{1}{8 x}-\frac{1}{192 x^3}+\frac{1}{640
   x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\pi x}\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{8 x}+\frac{1}{128 x^2}-\frac{5}{1024 x^3}-\frac{21}{32768
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right) \Bigg]$$

For $x=2$, the absolute error is $1.09\times 10^{-4}$ and it decreases very fast (for $n=20$, it is $3.79\times 10^{-9}$).